# How to load saved projects in burp suite free edition

Tags: security, penetration-testing, burp, penetration-tools

I am using Burp Suite Free edition for validating PEN Test in a Web Applications.

I have saved my projects in my local and closed the Burp suite.

I launched the Burp suite and try to load the saved project, via

```
Burp >> Project options >> Load Project options.
```

Project does not get loaded.

Is it possible to load the saved projects in Free edition?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Disk-based projects are a feature of Burp Professional only.

The feature you're seeing - Load/Save project options - relates to configuration only and won't persist data.

Comment: So how to load a saved project, which are created under Temporary project.

Comment: You can't load or save temporary projects. You will need to upgrade to Pro and use disk projects.